# How can I get a white background color to show up on night mode for Outlook on the browser?

Tags: html, css, email

Seems like Outlook on the browser is not accepting styles using the style attribute on HTML emails. So I'm using the bgcolor attribute on the table tag with an off white color (#fffffe) since I know white gets changed to a darker color. I still can't seem to display the white background color. Does anyone have any ideas?

`<table bgcolor="#fffffe" style="background-color: ##fffffe;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`